# Can I buy apps from the play store without having an Android phone?

Tags: google-play-store

How can I buy apps from the play store with only a google account and no phone? Planning to buy the phone next week, but would like to grab the sale prices for various apps before they expire.

Answer (score 4):

Generally, the answer is No. But there is a way to buy the apps first. Find a friend who is willing to let you add your account to his/her phone, then you can buy the apps under your own account.

Edit: Here's an [article](http://www.lifehacker.com.au/2012/03/ask-lh-can-i-buy-android-apps-without-an-android-phone/) I just came across.

Comment: A similar train of thought - will using an Android emulator on a PC also allow one to remote install apps/purchase apps via the Play Store?